# How do I make JQuery toggle not move elements around?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a responsive website menu which is openable with a burger (3 lines).

I've got the menu to open but it keeps moving the burger up and down in order to make way for it.

How do I make it so you click the burger and it stays in the SAME PLACE whilst opening the menu and playing its animation?

```
<div class="burger" id="burger" onclick="openBurger(this)">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
</center>
```

JS

```
function openBurger(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
}

$("#burger").click(function() { 
$("#nav").toggle();
});
```

Burger

[image]

As you can see, the burger bumps down to make space for the menu.
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Move your `#nav` HTML element below the `#burger` and should be fine.

Comment: Off topic: You seem to have a `center` tag closing a `div` tag.

Comment: Please show more markup. You need to include all the referenced elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hamburger menu should live independently from your nav list. With this example, you can include it before the list, and use jQuery to toggle the state of the navigation.

```js
$("#burger").click(function() {
    var state = $("#nav").attr("class");
    $("#nav").attr("class", state == "show" ? "hide" : "show");
});
```

```css
#burger { font-size: 32px; text-decoration: none; }
#nav { display: none; }
#nav.show { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="burger" href="#">☰</a>
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a class="bar1" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="bar2" href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li><a class="bar3" href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
```